# reading string and integers from a text file in java

Tags: java, text-files

```
/*This assignment is to create 2 parallel arrays – jobs& salaries
*Read file from “careers.txt” into arrays
*one line – job
*next line –salary
*Sort Salaries {from highest}
*then swap jobs if salary swapped
*Display output of careers and salaries from the highest on a formatted table.
* 
 */
package assignment7;
import java.util.*;//importing Scanner


public class Coordinator 
{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {// the main method creates the arrays and calls on each method to perform 
        //its work.
     String [] job = new String[20];//creating a string array having 20 spaces
     int[] salary = new int[20];//creating an integer array having 20 spaces
     int count;// number of spaces actually occupied in the array

     **count = readFile(job, salary);**// calling a method to read text into both
                                   //arrays and return the number of spaces 
                                   //occupied in the array

     sorter(job,salary,count);// calling on method to arrange file from highest
     //to lowest

     display(job, salary,count);// calling on method present the output


    }
    public static int readFile(String[] jobber, int[] salaro) throws Exception
    { // this method reads a text file and copies into arrays and also
        //returns the number of spaces occupied in the array
            int n = 0; //keeps track of number of times a line is fed into an 
            //array

            //set up a file class object linked up to the name of the file to 
            //be read
            java.io.File unread = new java.io.File("career.txt");

            // create a scanner instance to read the input from the file
            Scanner infile = new Scanner(unread);

            /*This while loop reads line of text into the arrays, it uses 
             * boolean
             * function hasNextLine() and the created scanner instance.
             */
            while (infile.hasNextLine() || infile.hasNextInt())
            {
                jobber[n] = infile.nextLine();
                **salaro[n] = infile.nextInt()**;
                n++;
            }//end while
            infile.close();//close scanner class
            return n;// return number of spaces filled

    }//end of readFile method


    public static void sorter(String[] jobestic, int[] salawe, int z) 
            throws Exception
    {// this method sorts the array from the highest paid job to the lowest.

      boolean swapped;// keeps track of when a swap takes place
      int i;// variable fo for loop
      int temp;// helps in swap
      String temp2;// helps in swap

      do
      {
          swapped = false;
          for (i= 0; i < z-1; i++)// a pass through the array
          {
              if (salawe[i+1] > salawe[i])
              // if the number before it is less they swap
              {
                  //swap starts
                  temp = salawe[i+1];
                  salawe[i+1] = salawe[i];
                  salawe[i] = temp;
                  //swaps the jobs too if the salary is swapped
                  temp2 = jobestic[i+1];
                  jobestic[i+1] = jobestic[i];
                  jobestic[i] = temp2;

                  swapped = true;
              }// end if


          }// end for

      } while (swapped);
   }// end sorter method

   public static void display(String[] jobo, int[] salary5 ,int k) throws Exception
   {

       //this method displays the output as a formatted table
       int i;
       System.out.printf("%-60s%15s%n", "Job", "Salary");





       for(i=0; i<k; i++)



           System.out.printf("%-60s%,15d%n", jobo[i], salary5[i]);

   }








}
```

Please Guys, what is wrong with this code? I have racked my brain over and over and can't figure out what is wrong.... I ran this code but i keep getting errors... The errors always indicate the bolded lines. The text file I'm trying to read from is below. I want to store the job titles in one array and the corresponding salaries in the other array. Like Parallel arrays. Please what is wrong with the code? I want to store the salaries as integers because i have format it as integers when I present the output.
Thank you.

```
Computer and Information Research Scientists
102190
Computer and Information Analysts
80460
Computer Systems Analysts
79680
Information Security Analysts
86170
Software Developers and Programmers
87100
Computer Programmers
74280
Software Developers(Applications)
90060
Software Developers(Systems Software)
99000
Web Developers
62500
Database and Systems Administrators and Network Architects
76880
Database Administrators
77080
Network and Computer Systems Administrators
72560
Computer Network Architects
91000
Computer Support Specialists
48900
Computer User Support Specialists
46420
Computer Network Support Specialists
59090
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException 
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909) 
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530) 
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160) 
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119) 
at assignment7.Coordinator.readFile(Coordinator.java:56)
at assignment7.Coordinator.main(Coordinator.java:25)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Stop.  Put all of this code aside.  Start a new project, focus JUST on File IO.  Make the code as simple as possible.  Try to figure out how to do File IO.  If you have a problem with that short, small, simple project, bring that here, so we don't have to read through tons of lines of code that have nothing to do with whatever problem you seem to be having.

Comment: @nhgrif I get your point but this code is for practising File IO and I seem to be having a problem somewhere. Please do help me go through it. Thank you.

Comment: @RaymondMachiraException in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at assignment7.Coordinator.readFile(Coordinator.java:56)
 at assignment7.Coordinator.main(Coordinator.java:25)

Comment: Start with something simpler.  Once you figure out how to do the most simplistic version of File IO, implement what you know into the project you have here.

Comment: And by the way, your error message points specifically to exactly where your error is occuring.  Coordinator.java line 25 and line 56.  What are those lines?

Comment: @nhgrif How do I correct the error?

Comment: @nhgrif line 25 - count = readFile(job, salary); line 56 - salaro[n] = infile.nextInt();

Comment: I'm not going to count all of those lines to figure out which one is 25 and which one is 56.  I was asking you to highlight those specific lines.  And this just reinforces the point I was making.  The code you have posted is to big and cumbersome to get effective help via StackOverflow.  Start a new project, figure out File IO, then apply what you learn in that project to this project.

Comment: When I made salary, a string array it kinda worked but then i could not format the output

Comment: @nhgrif I'm sorry it looks cumbersome. It is actually just filled with comments.

Comment: @nhgrif please continue with your help. I have already practised reading strings from a text file. Here, I moved it further by trying to read strings and integers from the same file. Like, the first line is read into the string array, the second into the integer array, the third line into the string array, the fourth into the Integer array... etc. That's what I'm trying to  do but it's not working. Do you know why?

Comment: Personally, I read everything from files (or any input really) into `String` variables, and then use other techniques for getting an `int` or anything else out of the string.

Comment: @nhgrif Please, Examples of such techniques? I want to be able to arrange the integers from the highest to the lowest and also print out a formatted output(having commas, decimal points..etc). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question, or its equivalent, seems to get asked every few days.

When you call `nextInt()`, your scanner stops after the number.  Then when you call `nextLine()` immediately afterwards, you're actually reading the new-line character at the end of the line that had the number on.  You're not reading the next line.  So on the next iteration of the loop, you're calling `nextInt()` when you've got non-numeric text lined up next in your scanner.

Add an extra call to `nextLine()` after every call to `nextInt()`, just to read that extra new-line character.